# Finding duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have 3 columns UserId,Map,MapId in table MapUser

I need to display duplicate values in MapID where the Map=GLOBCOHS and need to see the UserID value against the duplicate Values

eg.

```
UserId  Map     MapId
1   GLOBCOHS    5
2   GLOBCOHS    6
3   COHS        7
4   GLOBCOHS    5
5   GLOBCOHS    6
6   GLOBCOHS    10
7   COHS        12
```

I need to see:

```
UserId  Map      MapId
1      GLOBCOHS     5
2      GLOBCOHS     6
4      GLOBCOHS     5
5      GLOBCOHS     6
```

I've tried the below code but it only give me the duplicated GLOBCOHS Maps and their MapId without pointing to the UserId

```
Select SystemCode, MapId, Count(*)
From dbo.CpartyMap
where SystemCode='GLOBCOHS'
Group by SystemCode, MapId
Having Count(*) > 1
```

*Only have few hours of SQL experience so absolute newbie :)

thanks

Comment: what is "SystemCode"

Comment: i assume your using SQL Server as i notice dbo in your query statement.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you would use window functions:

```
select pm.*
from (select pm.*,
             count(*) over (partition by SystemCode, mapid) as cnt_map
      from dbo.CpartyMap pm
      where SystemCode = 'GLOBCOHS'
     ) pm
where cnt_map >= 2;
```